# Proving function is $C^k$

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from an exercise in Way of Analysis (section 10.2.4 problem 20).

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^k$ and $f$ is even, then show $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x) = f(|x|)$ is also $C^k$.

$C^k$ just means the function has $k$ continuous derivatives, and $|x|$ is referring to the regular Euclidean norm.

I am not sure how to use the fact $f$ is even in the proof and having trouble for a general $k$. Any hints, even on a particular case like $k=2$, are welcome.

My workings:

As a comment suggests $f(x) = F(x)$ for $n = 1$. For $n = 2$, $F(x) = f(\sqrt {x_1^2 + x_2^2}).$ I'm stuck on where to proceed from here. Is there some form of induction here that I am not seeing?

Comment: Note that when $n=1$, $f$ even means that $f(x)=f(\mid x\mid)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please include what you have tried so far and why you got stuck, this will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I edited in some details - though unfortunately I did not make much progress.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start: Suppose $f \in C^2(\mathbb {R}).$ Note $f$ even implies $f'$ is odd. This is key, because it tells us$f'(0)=0.$ So letting $P_2$ denote the second degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0,$ we have $P_2(t) = f(0) + f''(0)t^2/2.$ Clearly $P_2(|x|)\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}^n).$

Set $g(t)= f(t)-P_2(t).$ Then $g\in C^2$ and $0=g(0)=g'(0)=g''(0).$ So it's enough to check that $G(x) = g(|x|)$ is $C^2.$ We certainly have $G \in C^2(\mathbb {R}^n\setminus \{0\}).$ Suppose $D$ is a partial derivative of order $\le 2.$ If we show that $D(G)$ tends to $0$ at the origin, then it will follow that $G \in C^2(\mathbb {R}^n).$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tedious & unsatisfactory answer. I suspect there is a simpler answer, but it evades me. It is unsatisfactory because it relies on
the Faà di Bruno [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version) (in particular, see the Michael Hardy 
[reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#cite_note-3))
for derivatives of compositions. This is unsatisfactory purely because it
is a little opaque, and not part of everybody's bag of tricks. I also
use multi index [notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation#Definition_and_basic_properties), mainly to preserve my notational sanity.

The proof follows the following lines:

1. Reduce the problem to showing that $\rho(x)= r(\|x\|)$ is $C^k$,
   where $r^{(i)}(0) = 0$, for $i=0,...,k$.
2. Find a suitable bound for the derivatives of $x \mapsto \|x\|$, for $x \neq 0$.
3. Show the relevant derivatives of $\rho$, for $x \neq 0$, converge to $0$ as $x \to 0$.
4. Show the relevant derivatives of $\rho$ are differentiable
   at $x=0$ and that the derivatives are zero.

First a few notes:

Note that if a $C^1$ function $g$ is even, then $g'$ is odd and hence $g'(0) = 0$. If a $C^1$ function $g$ is odd, then $g'$ is even. Hence if $g$ is an even $C^k$ function, then the odd derivatives satisfy $g^{2i+1}(0) = 0$.

Let $n(x) = \|x\|$, we note that $n$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$, and $n^2$ is smooth everywhere.

Let $\phi = f \circ n$. If $f$ is $C^k$, then $\phi $ is $C^k$ for $x \neq 0$. Hence the only issue here is to show that $\phi$ is $C^k$ at zero (meaning the relevant derivatives exist at zero and are continuous there).

Now the reduction:

Since $f$ is $C^k$ and even, Taylor's theorem shows that there is some that $C^k$ function $r$ such that
$f(t) = \sum_{i=0, \text{even}}^k {f^{(i)}(0) \over i! } t^i + r(t)$, and $r$
satisfies $r^{(i)}(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}{r^{(i)}(t) \over t^{k-i}} = 0$ for $i=0,...,k$. Since the Taylor polynomial only involves even terms, and $n^2$ is smooth, we see that showing $\phi$ is $C^k$ is equivalent to showing
that $\rho=r \circ n$ is $C^k$. So, we need to show that
$\rho$ is $C^k$. In light of the above comments, we need only deal with
the point $x=0$.

We will need a technical bound on $r$: Note that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta \in (0,1]$ such that if $|t|< \delta$, then
$|r^{(i)}(t)| \le \epsilon | t^{k-i} | $, for all $i=0,...,k$.

Now the tedium:

Suppose $x \neq 0$. We have
${\partial n(x) \over \partial x_i} = {x_i \over \|x\|}$ for all $i$. Now let
$\alpha$ be a multi index, then I claim that
${\partial^\alpha n(x) \over \partial x^\alpha}$ has the form
${\partial^\alpha n(x) \over \partial x^\alpha} = {p_\alpha(x) \over \|x\|^{2 |\alpha|-1}}$ for some polynomial $p_\alpha$, that satisfies $\partial p_\alpha = |\alpha|$ (that is the degree is $\alpha$) and $p_\alpha(x) = 0$. Note that
${\partial^\alpha n(x) \over \partial x^\alpha} = {\partial^\beta n(x) \over \partial x^\beta}$ if $\beta$ is a permutation of $\alpha$ since $n$ is smooth (in particular, the order of differentiation is unimportant).
The result is
true for $|\alpha| = 1$.
Then ${\partial \over \partial x_i}{\partial^\alpha n(x) \over \partial x^\alpha} = {\|x\|^2{\partial p_\alpha(x) \over \partial x_i} -(2k-1) x_i p_\alpha(x) \over \|x\|^{2 |\alpha|+1}} $, and so we see the result is true
for any index $\beta$ such that $|\beta|=|\alpha|+1$.

We note that since $\partial p_\alpha = |\alpha|$, we have
$| {\partial^\alpha n(x) \over \partial x^\alpha} | \le {K_\alpha \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-1}}$ for some constant
$K_\alpha$.

The Faà di Bruno formula gives, for $x \neq 0$,
${\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha} = \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} 
r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x))\prod_{\beta \in \pi} {\partial^\beta n (x) \over \partial x^\beta} $,
where ${\cal P}$ is the set of partitions of a $|\alpha|$ element subset of $1,...,n$ (and $|\alpha| \le k$, since $r$ is $C^k$).

(As an aside, to allow repetitions as in ${\partial^2 \over \partial x_i^2}$, strictly speaking we do not use partitions, but a modification
thereof that uses multi sets. The end result is the same, but involves even
more notation.)

We can use the above bound to get
\begin{eqnarray}
|{\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha}|  &\le& \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} 
| r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x)) | \prod_{\beta \in \pi} {K_\beta \over \|x\|^{|\beta|-1}} \\
&=& \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} 
| r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x)) | { \prod_{\beta \in \pi} K_\beta \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-|\pi|}}  \\
&=&
\sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} { | r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x)) | \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-|\pi|}} \prod_{\beta \in \pi} K_\beta 
\end{eqnarray}
Since $|\pi| \le |\alpha| \le k $, we see that 
${ | r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x)) | \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-|\pi|}} \to 0$ and so
${\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha} \to 0$.

Finally, we need to show that for $|\alpha| < k$, the function $x \mapsto {\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha}$ is differentiable with  derivative zero.

In the following I am using the technical result for $r$ mentioned above:

Since $|\rho(x)-\rho(0) -0\cdot x| = |r(n(x))| \le \epsilon \|x\|$, we see that $\rho$ is differentiable with derivative zero, hence the result is true for $|\alpha|=1$. How suppose the result is true for $|\alpha| < k$, then,
using the fact that $|r^{(i)}(n(x))| \le \epsilon \|x\|^{k-i}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
|{\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha} - {\partial^\alpha \rho (0) \over \partial x^\alpha} - 0 \cdot x| &= & |{\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha}| \\
&\le& \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} { | r^{(|\pi|)}(n(x)) | \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-|\pi|}} \prod_{\beta \in \pi} K_\beta \\
&\le& \epsilon \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}} { \|x\|^{k-|\pi|} \over \|x\|^{|\alpha|-|\pi|}} \prod_{\beta \in \pi} K_\beta \\
= \epsilon \|x\|^{k-|\alpha|} \sum_{\pi \in {\cal P}}  \prod_{\beta \in \pi} K_\beta
\end{eqnarray}
It follows from this that $x \mapsto {\partial^\alpha \rho (x) \over \partial x^\alpha}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and has derivative zero, hence the result is true for derivatives of order $\beta$ such that $|\beta|=|\alpha|+1$.